# No me arranca el Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una pc de 32bits, quiero iniciar android studio pero no inicia, vi tutoriales y agregan variables de entorno y yo lo hice pero me sigue sin iniciar el android studio [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido, Lo primero que debes asegurar es que instalaste android studio de 32 bits. Agrega más detalles, ¿Que error te muestra?.Revisa como realizar una pregunta en el sitio y tengas buenas respuestas [ask]. Realiza el [tour] para que conozcas su funcionamiento.

Comment: Instala Android Studio( 32-bits) https://developer.android.com/studio/

Comment: Necesitas instalar la version de 32 bits de android studio y tambien la version de 32 bits de jdk y para comprobar que todo funciona abre un cmd y escribe java o javac asi sabras q instalaste java correctamente